# Automatically save documents from a scanner to a network folder

Tags: networking

I am needing to hook up a Cannon DR225 scanner to the network at the office. We will have 3 users that are terrified of technology so I would like it if I could set up the scanner to automatically save scanned documents into a networked folder with just a date/time hash as the file name without having to use an interface on the computers. Just push the button and move on. Is this possible? If it is how? The software has something it calls full auto mode but that still makes me pick save location and file name every time. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

According to http://usa.canon.com/cusa/office/standard_display/Scanner_BundledSoftware

> Nocson EasyScanToFTP
>   EasyScanToFTP is a utility designed specifically for Canon imageFORMULA scanners that allows users to seamlessly upload images directly to FTP servers. To download EasyScanToFTP for imageFORMULA scanners from Nocson's website at no additional charge, click here.

I would setup a simple FTP server and give that a try.

Comment: `Nocson EasyScanToFTP EasyScanToFTP` that name. THAT NAAAAAAAME.